# How to remove tabs and newlines with a regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

In Python 3.x, the special re sequence '\s' matches Unicode whitespace characters including  [ \t\n\r\f\v].

The following piece of code is intended to replace tabs and newlines with a space.

```
import re
text = """Hello my friends.
    How are you doing?
I'm fine."""
output = re.sub('\s', ' ', text)
print(output)
```

However, the tab is still present in output. Why?

Comment: Are you sure the "tab" isn't just a bunch of spaces? Most (if not all) IDEs replace a tab with four spaces. Use `\t` for a tab, and it will work.

Comment: ...but the point of my question is, '\s' is supposed to include '  ', '\n' and '\t'

Comment: Yes, but it will replace each whitespace character with a space. A group of spaces will remain a group of spaces. Use `r'\s+'` instead if you want to replace a group of whitespace characters with a single whitespace.

Comment: @user1975053 We can't know. What is here on SO is a bunch of spaces. Check if you can go from `How` to the beginning of the line by pressing 4 times the left arrow, if you can, then these are spaces.

Comment: Do you want tabs to be replaced by a single space, or something like 4 spaces?

Comment: Oh, the question input window does not seem to accept tabs! If I press on the tabulator I get thrown out(?)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is(likely) that your tab character is just a bunch of spaces.

```
>>> re.sub(r"\s+", " ", text)
"Hello my friends. How are you doing? I'm fine."
```

Comment: It indeed is in my question, but it isn't in my original code. How can you enter a tab in a SO question?

Comment: @user1975053 other than expressing a tab as "\t" I don't believe you can.  So the best you could do with your question is change your string to "Hello my friends.\n\tHow are you doing?\nI'm fine."

Comment: Thanks a gizillion. Found a lot of answers to remove **all** white spaces in a text making the text useless for NLP. This is the only one that preserves white spaces between words removing only extra white spaces. Oh and it also preserves German Umlauts. :-)